# Extract Line of Text Between 2 Words in XML file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, token

I'm trying to write a simple batch to extract some specific text from a xml file.

The file is always in the same place and the text I need to extract is a UNC path, so will always vary, but will always be between the same points:-

From the content of the file (below) I want to echo the C:\Somefolder\somewhere
from between the 2 serverpath entries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClientConfigurationFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ServerPath>C:\somefolder\somewhere</ServerPath>
```

I've had a look around and found similar but nothing quite matches my need. Also tried to tweak some existing tokens delims I have in other batches.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=  " %%A IN (C:\Test\file.xml) DO SET FOLDER=%%A
echo %FOLDER%
pause
```

I've tried this but I dont think i'm on the money the delims is the 2 spaces before line I want to extract, but tokens 1,2 or 3 just doesn't yield the desired results.

I would to just run my batch and echo back the path between ServerPath and ServerPath

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Second, `delims` is a list of single characters to treat as delimiter(s), not a delimiter string. **First: DON'T mess with the system variable `%PATH%`, unless you exactly know what it does and what you do.**

Comment: Bad example yes, I'm just trying to demonstrate I need that path between those two points variable could be anything, will edit, thanks

Comment: `@For /F "Tokens=3Delims=<>" %%A In ('FindStr /IR "<ServerPath>" "C:\Test\file.xml" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "URL=%%A"` may work for you.

Comment: That's kind of one liner I would like to have, sadly not echoing back the path, variable doesn't seem to get set. Thanks though.

Comment: Don't use batch files for XML parsing, use a language that natively supports XML data; otherwise (when treating XML just as normal text) you will run into problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch isn't the right choice for processing XML files, but if the formatting is known, it's possible:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('find "<ServerPath>" "C:\Test\file.xml"') do set "Serverpath=%%a"
echo %serverpath%
```

Note: this works with a file exactly as shown in your question. No guarantee for correct results, if the formatting of the `XML` file changes.

Comment: Yes! You did it, please can you explain the tokens and delims part so I might have better luck going solo.

Comment: it's well explained [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) plus some examples. You may want to bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt)

Answer (score 0):

try with [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) (if this is a valid xml):

```
call xpath.bat test.xml "//ServerPath"
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('xpath.bat test.xml "//ServerPath"') do set "server_path=%%~a"
echo %server_path%
```

Comment: Thanks for this, hoping to not have to rely on anything else, but this maybe the answer depending what happens.